# Unfuddle with Subversion

Tags: svn, unfuddle

Can I use "Unfuddle" without the need to have a subversion/GIT account? It is my understanding that these revision/versioning tools sit under Unfuddle which is a hosted application.

If this is the case, how does one upload source code as I cannot see any obvious way via the Unfuddle dashboard.

GF

PS I asked a similar question earlier but I felt it wasn't worded as well as the above and so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading "subclipse" (a subversion plugin for Eclipse). From there I could upload to my subversion repository hosted by "Unfuddle". Excellent little service.

Thanks for all the help (not).:.))

GF

Comment: there are plenty of guides online for help with subversion...  subversion and GIT are not global entities where you have ONE account - like facebook or something.

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse

Click **SVN** menu

```
- Click 'Checkout Projects from SVN'

- 'Create a new repository location'

- Just enter the unfuddle URL (http://(subdomain).unfuddle.com/svn/subdomain_repository abbreviation (Provided when creating a new svn repository in unfuddle) )
       Ex: http://xyz.unfuddle.com/svn/xyz_rep
       xyz - subdomain
       rep - abbreviation
```

Create source directories/folders in eclipse and commit the changes to unfuddle online repository.